# Adding gaps at specific intervals on the x-axis in a ggplot bar graph

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a mocked up data set here that I would like to introduce larger gaps into on the x-axis at particular intervals.

I would like these gaps to be larger specifically between the day groups.

In this case, the would be a larger gap after the first 2 groups, then after the second 2 groupings, then after the next 3 groups, so on...

Here is my current output:
[image: Current graph output]

Here is my code:

```
library("ggplot2")
library("grid")
library("dplyr")

df <- data.frame(
  day = c(rep(11, 6), rep(12, 6), rep(23, 9), rep(31, 9), rep(47, 9)),
  hz = c(rep(1, 3), rep(2, 3), rep(1, 3), rep(2, 3), rep(1, 3), rep(2, 3), rep(4, 3) , rep(1, 3), rep(2, 3), rep(4, 3), rep(1, 3), rep(2, 3), rep(4, 3)),
  ft = c(38,42,45,28,30,45,38,41,45,25,30,45,45,43,50,30,28,48,30,33,40,45,41,47,38,35,43,30,32,50,46,40,50,38,30,40,30,28,40),
  sp = c(rep(c("Ctrl", "Absrc", "Ab42"), 13))
)

se <- function(a) sd(a)/sqrt(length(a))

g1 <- ggplot(df, aes(x=interaction(hz, day), y=ft, group=desc(sp), fill=sp)) +
  geom_bar(position=position_dodge(), stat="identity") +
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymax=ft+se(ft), ymin=ft-se(ft)), position=position_dodge(0.9), width=0.5) +
  coord_cartesian(ylim=c(0, 60)) +
  annotate("text", x=c(1.5, 3.5, 6, 9, 12), y=-6, label=c("day 11", "day 12", "day 23", "day 31", "day 47")) +
  annotate("text", x=1:13, y=-3, label=c(rep(c("1 hz", "2hz"), 2), rep(c("1 hz", "2 hz", "4hz"), 3))) +
  theme_classic() + 
  theme(plot.margin=unit(c(1,1,4,1), "lines"),
        axis.title.x= element_blank(),
        axis.text.x=element_blank()) + 
  scale_fill_discrete(breaks=c("Ctrl", "Absrc", "Ab42")) + 
  scale_fill_grey() + 
  scale_y_continuous(expand=c(0,0))


g2 <- ggplot_gtable(ggplot_build(g1))
g2$layout$clip[g2$layout$name == "panel"] <- "off"
grid.draw(g2)

ggsave(file="graph.svg", plot=g2)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option would be to use facetting which also allows to add the labels for the days without the need of the `annotate` hack. And in case you don't want the gaps on the axis you could set the panel spacing to zero and instead increase the expansion of the x scale to add some more space between the panels:

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(df, aes(x = interaction(hz, day), y = ft, group = desc(sp), fill = sp)) +
  geom_bar(position = position_dodge(), stat = "identity") +
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymax = ft + se(ft), ymin = ft - se(ft)), position = position_dodge(0.9), width = 0.5) +
  scale_x_discrete(labels = ~paste(substr(.x, 1, 1), "hz")) +
  facet_grid(.~day, switch = "x", scales = "free_x", space = "free_x",
             labeller = labeller(day = ~ paste("day", .x))) +
  coord_cartesian(ylim = c(0, 60), clip = "off") +
  theme_classic() +
  theme(
    plot.margin = unit(c(1, 1, 1, 1), "lines"),
    axis.title.x = element_blank(),
    strip.background.x = element_blank(),
    strip.placement = "outside",
    #panel.spacing.x = unit(0, "pt")
  ) +
  scale_fill_grey(breaks = c("Ctrl", "Absrc", "Ab42")) +
  scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0, 0))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much, I actually quite like the white space in the x-axis line, too.
One day I will get the hang of R without being so hacky!